Google Chrome opens but window does not appear on Ubuntu 22.04
Summary
When attempting to open Google Chrome v124.0.6367.60 on Ubuntu 22.04, the app appears as if it's opened based on the task bar (icon appears, camera even turns on since the last tab I had open was a Google meet), but the window does not appear. It creates a ghost/artifact that if I run another window over it, it creates all sorts of fun display artifacts (see screenshot). I can maximize, minimize, resize the strange artifact but Chrome otherwise does not display properly at all.
Screenshot:
Strange screen artifact, settings window dragged in front of it

Terminal output:
[42153:42153:0423/153731.352677:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#141 is a dynamic-sized tensor).
[42672:21:0423/153801.274372:ERROR:rtp_transceiver.cc(81)] Invalid codec preferences: invalid codec with name "AV1". (INVALID_MODIFICATION)

What I've Tried

Updating all software
Rebooting the machine
Uninstalling, purging, & reinstalling Chrome
All suggestions from
Chrome or chromium window doesn't appear after opening
Google Chrome Beta - This worked! But I don't want to be on Beta forever. Do I need to just wait until google-chrome-stable is updated to 125?


Same problem here. I managed to work around it by launching Chrome with Wayland flags:
google-chrome --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland


This also worked for me, There is a way to do this permanent?
I tried to change the .desktop at /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop adding the options but no luck.
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --eanble-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland


Looks like you misspelled “enable”, is that exactly what you have in your .desktop file? It worked for me to edit as you describe.

google-chrome-stable uses X11 as the preferred platform backend under Linux.
If explicitly selecting Wayland as the platform backend is a working solution (i.e., google-chrome-stable --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland starts Chrome successfully), then google-chrome-stable can be configured to prefer Wayland:
Open chrome://flags and search for the Preferred Ozone platform flag (chrome://flags/#ozone-platform-hint). Change its configuration to Auto or Wayland.
Exit Chrome for the new setting to take effect.
From now onwards, executing google-chrome-stable should use Wayland.
